# Naming and appending list of lists inside a loop

Tags: r, list, loops, append

I´m creating a list by appending lists based on a loop by State and naming each sub-list with the name of each State:

```
library(rlist)
States=c("VA", "MA", "PA")
j=1
for (i in States) {
   i=list(population=something, size=something)

   if (j==1) {
     total_list <- list(i=get(i))
     j=2
    }
    else total_list <- list.append(total_list,i=get(i))

}
```

It works but every sublist is name "i" instead of the name of the state; if I try including get(I)=get(I) I get an error. How could I make the names work? and also any suggestion to improve this code will be welcome.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying but package `hash` seems like useful for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Where are you getting population and size from, and would that not already have state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not familiar with the rlist package but if I was working in base R and I understand your question I would do something like this:

```
States=c("VA", "MA", "PA")
stateList <- vector("list", length(States))
for(i in 1:length(States)){
   stateList[[i]] <- list(population = something, size = something)
}
names(stateList) <- States
```

Once again not familiar with rlist but generally if you know the size of any object its much more efficient to declare it rather than add to it.